# Not able to load properties file for Hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, properties

I'm trying to load details which are defined in properties file into Hibernate.cfg.xml.

### Hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">${driverClassName}</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">${url}</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">${username}</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">${password}</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">${dialect}</property>

<!-- Ehcache config -->          
<property   name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
<property name="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">/ehcache.xml</property>

<!-- c3p0 Connection pool config -->
<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">100</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>  
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.validate">true</property>

<property name="hibernate.c3p0.privilegeSpawnedThreads">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.contextClassLoaderSource">library</property>



<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="format_sql">true</property>
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

<!-- Mapping model classes -->
<mapping class="com.Dashboard" />
```

### Hibernate util class

```
public class HibernateUtil {

private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try {

        Properties dbConnectionProperties = new Properties();
        try {
            System.out.println("Loading Properties file for Hibernate config");
            dbConnectionProperties.load(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("db.properties"));
            System.out.println("Loaded Properties file for Hibernate config");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            // Log
        }

        // load from different directory
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().mergeProperties(dbConnectionProperties).configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                .buildSessionFactory();

        return sessionFactory;

    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

public static void shutdown() {
    // Close caches and connection pools
    System.out.println("Closing session factory");
    getSessionFactory().close();
}

}
```

### Stacktrace

```
  Initial SessionFactory creation  failed.org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested   service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
Apr 25, 2016 9:18:19 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse   mapMappableContainerException
SEVERE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not   be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.util.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:32)
at com.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:9)
at com.impl.PersonalisationImpl.<init>(PersonalisationImpl.java:38)
at com.service.GetWidgetDetails.getUserById(GetWidgetDetails.java:25)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:209)
at com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:244)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create      requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
at      org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(Abstrac    tServiceRegistryImpl.java:244)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:208)
at   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractSe    rviceRegistryImpl.java:189)
at    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.j   ava:51)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureServic    e(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:692)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
at com.util.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:25)
... 48 more
```

### Db.propeties

```
driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/indsu
username=root
password=root
dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

Comment: Please, add a full stack trace, and full `hibernate.cfg.xml` and a Hibernate version.

Comment: what is your project structure. do you use maven or spring java project or a normal java project. upload that

Comment: Its a simple Java web application project. Not maven not spring.

Comment: @v.ladynev Hibernate version is 5.x and updated full stack and hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: @Syed There is non `Error accessing stax stream` message in the stack trace.

Comment: @v.ladynev I'm sorry, when i clean the project, this is the error it is showing.

Comment: @Syed Is it really a full stack trace? Maybe you miss a part with a cause of this `Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]`.

Comment: @v.ladynev, yes its also available in stacktrace

Comment: @Syed I mean Why this happens `Unable to create requested service`?

Comment: @v.ladynev I don't know too. It happens only when I try to get values from db.properties

Comment: @Syed Please, add your `db.properties`

Answer (score 0):

Properties form `db.properties` should be used not by Hibernate (with `mergeProperties()`), but it should be placed by Spring in place of this

`<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">${driverClassName}</property>`

A simply workaround just remove `db.properties` and hardcore properties form it in place of `${driverClassName}` and others. And you don't need to use `mergeProperties()` anyway.

For an example

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
```

Comment: Then what should be used for Hibernate? I'm not using Spring

Comment: @Syed You can set properties in the `hibernate.properties` (with valid names). Or replace all placeholders like `${driverClassName}` with property values.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: you are just using <property> value as it is.... I don't want to use it in that fashion, I require to get it from properties file

Comment: @Syed Add such properties in `hibernate.properties` (with valid names). Or load it by your way (valid names). Anyway delete properties with place holders from `hibernate.cfg.xml` (it is for Spring).

Comment: I'm confused. I need to create hibernate.properties file again? What are valid names? Please explain me a bit clearly. Do I need to put all key value pairs as it is which I've defined.

Comment: @Syed You need to rename your `Db.propeties` to `hibernate.properties`. Hibernate will load it automatically. With valid I mean `driverClassName` becomes `hibernate.connection.driver_class`.

Comment: OK. I understood in this way. 1)Rename Db.propeties to hibernate.properties 2) driverClassName becomes hibernate.connection.driver_class, url becomes hibernate.connection.url etc........and in Hibernate.cfg.xml, It should be like <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">${hibernate.connection.driver_class}</property> Am I right?

Comment: @Syed `<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">${hibernate.connection.driver_class}</p‌​roperty>` — this should be deleted. Hibernate loads properties from `hibernate.properties` automatically (it should be in the root of `src` foulder, of course).